# Setting working directory R error u2069 cannot change working directory

Tags: r, working-directory, setwd

Whenever I try to set the working directory I get an error message that says

```
Error in setwd("/Users/myname/Wedding\u2069") : 
  cannot change working directory
```

Specifically, the directory path is followed by "`u2069`"

I am working from a Mac. Any suggestions?

Comment: Strange. `\u2069` seems to suggest Unicode character ["Pop Directional Isolate"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2069/index.htm), which may originate from using different text base directions. Can you provide more details involving your OS, locale and language settings?

Comment: I'm using Mac Mojave OS, am based in the United States, with English as the language. This is the first time this has happened to me.

Comment: try using `/` instead of `\ `?

Comment: So is `u2069` actually the name of a folder? In that case, see @RAB's advice.

Comment: That didn't work. Received this message: "Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\U""

Comment: u2069 isn't the name of the folder. The directory entered was this: "setwd("/Users/myname/Wedding"). The error message added the u2069 and reported this: Error in setwd("/Users/myname/Wedding\u2069") : 
  cannot change working directory

Comment: That's very odd; so the `\u2069` really does seem to relate to the afore-mentioned Unicode character. Did you add support for multiple input sources on your Mac and switch between them?

Comment: Also: Does the problem persist when you restart your Mac and open a fresh R session from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem running R 3.6.2. on a Mac. Deleting the apostrophe or quotation characters around the working directory, typing them in again and then running the command worked. I can't quite explain it, but this does appear to be some sort of encoding/formatting problem.